# Intersection point of tangent line with $X$ axis

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

i have confused in one  topic and please help me,suppose that we have  following function
$f(x)=x^3+x^2-2*x-3)$
we know that there is a tangent of this function which goes through point $(1,-3)$,we are required to  find abscissa,where  this tangent intersect ox axis.
what i have tried first it to find derivative,so we have
($f(x)'=3*x^2+2*x-2)$,now what does mean abscissa of intersection of tangent line with ox axis?if it means that,it includes every point where y=0,then answer is this

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3*x%5E2%2B2*x-2%3D0
```

but if it is y value at $x=0$,then answer is $-2$,so i am confused about this and please help me,also what i should  do if instead of  ox axis,,we are required to find ordinate of intersection  of tangent line with oy  axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative gives the slope of the tangent line at that point.  In your case, if you evaluate $f'(1)$ you get $3$.  The tangent line is then the line through $(1,-3)$ with slope $3$.  The [point-slope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-slope_formula#Point.E2.80.93slope_form) form of the line is then $y-(-3)=3(x-1)$.  On the $x$ axis, $y=0$, so you substitute that in to find $x$.

Comment: so it means that,ordinate of oy axis intersection would be at x=0?

Comment: @dato:  Correct.

Comment: thanks @ Ross Millikan ,good night